# How would you abstract this functionality?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Observe the following classes and their containment:

`Section` has an `ItemList` which has many `Item`s

But lets say an `Item` is rendered a different color based on some complicated algorithm that is based off the `Section.name` it is contained in.

What's the proper/best way to go about abstracting this functionality? Is there a common design pattern that occurs in situations like these? Or is the inherent design flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate your data structures/models from your logic and processing of them. That said, I would make your Item have a `Section` reference on it referencing it's `Section`, when you add an `Item` to the `ItemList`, ensure the add method looks at the `ItemList`s `Section` (parent) and sets the reference on the `Item`. Same goes for the setter on the `ItemList` in the `Section`, it would have to iterate each `Item` and set the `Section`.

Alternatively, you could make the `Section` set on the getter of the `ItemList` as lazy semantics, that would be entirely up to you depending on the use of your `Section` the performance statistics would be different between these two approaches.

Further, I would write some form of renderer that took an `Item` and knew how to render it which would look at the `Section` on the `Item` and the `Name` on that `Section`.

You may want to render an entire section, but I would write that renderer separate and it would use the `ItemRenderer` to render each `Item`.

As an aside, you may want to use a form of `IObservableCollection` and have the `Item` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well so that you could then maintain synchrony both between the rendered version and the item, and synchronize the `Item` with the `Section` it exists in by an event registration that updates the `Section` property appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

What does the rendering? If it's something in `Section`, or outside of all of these, but accessing the `Item`s from the `Section`, then there's nothing more needed.

If it's in `Item`, then you just need to make sure `Item` knows what `Section` it belongs to, or can obtain it (e.g. by having an ID it can look up on - useful with languages that make dealing with circular references tricky, but not needless hassle otherwise).

Since the first case causes no difficulty, it's clearly to be preferred over the second, so the closest to a design-pattern is that if you find yourself doing this sort of work in the contained item, to try and move it up to the container, or outside of them all. Beyond that, there isn't much of a problem to need solving.

Answer (score 0):

I would build an `ItemRenderer` class that knows the algorithm, and pass in the references to each `Item` you would like to render and the `Section` it was contained in.

It may also make sense to let each `Item` know the section it belongs to, but I would still let the `ItemRenderer` handle the rendering.